# Fatal Error after moving site from one host to another

Tags: php, wordpress, parsing

I have recently moved a website from one host to another and all went smoothly except one plugin wont reactivate due to the following error:

Fatal error: Cannot redeclare NDScoutsGallery::update() in /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/plugins/ndscouts.php on line 115

This is the line of code it is referring to:

function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {

I have attempted to sort however was unsuccessful. Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The update function is already created in word press, You can rename the function Name in NDScoutsGallery and call using updated function. It will work

Comment: I cannot find where you mean to change the function name. Could you confirm please?